# How to define getters and setters in a loop?

Tags: javascript, getter-setter

I want to define setters and getters in the following way:

```
var myObj = {
    // this is the object that should be 
    // filled with new setters and getters
    ...
}
/**
* This object contains getters and setters for myObj
*/
var Fields = {
   param1: {defaultValue: ..., type: ..., ...}
   param2: ...
}
// so the following code doesn't work properly
for (var field in Fields)
    Object.__defineGetter__(field, function() {
        // do smth
    });
```

this code leads to that all the getters are doing the same stuff 
(corresponding to the last iteration of the for loop)

How should I modify the code to make it work properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap the body of the `for` loop in an anonymous function, in this way:

```
for (var field in Fields){
    (function(field){
        myObj.__defineGetter__(field, function() {
            // do something, pointing to unique variables using "field"
            // Example:
            doSomethingSpecial(Fields[field].defaultValue);
        });
    })(field)
}
```

This method's effect is based on the fact that (anonymous) functions have an own scope. The primitive variables (strings, numbers) are passed by value as an argument to the function. Because of this, the `field` property inside the anonymous function is distinct from the `field` property, defined in the loop.
When the value of `field` (outside the function) is changed, the `field` variable *inside* the function does not change.

I have also replaced `Object` by`myObj`. If that's incorrect, revert the change.

Comment: Yeah, that's the thing I needed! Thnx!

Comment: The use of `__defineGetter__` [is discouraged](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/__defineGetter__). Use [defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) instead.

Comment: See also [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23308747/969483) for an example.

Answer (score 2):

This feature is only avaliable in Firefox.

In this link http://www.codeproject.com/KB/scripting/crossbrowserjavascript.aspx shows that.

"The **defineGetter** and **defineSetter** are unique features to Mozilla/FireFox and you can find some (still few) samples on the internet by searching through Google for these keywords."

Answer (score 1):

var properties=['asd','asd2','asd3'];

```
var myob = function(){};

for(var x=0;x<properties.length;x++)
{
    var p = properties[x];

    var getter = function(){ return this['_' + arguments.callee.propname]; };
    getter.propname = p;
    myob.prototype.__defineGetter__(p, getter);


    var setter = function(value){ this['_' + arguments.callee.propname] = value; };
    setter.propname = p;
    myob.prototype.__defineSetter__(p, setter);
}


var myobi = new myob();

myobi.asd = 33;
alert(myobi._asd);
alert(myobi.asd);
myobi.asd2 = 44;
alert(myobi._asd2);
alert(myobi.asd2);
```

HTH!